# How to run python script before any stack updates using Sceptre

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sceptre

I have a Python script that I'd like to run before any stack is updated and deployed. From my research, I know I need to use hooks and likely the hook point `before_update`.

What I can't find is the syntax for running a python script from the hook, and how to ensure that the script runs every time ANY of my stacks are updated (ie. I don't want to have to write the hook for every stack, but have this hook set globally instead if possible).

I'm assuming the place to write the hook would be in `cloudformation\config\config.yaml` but would love confirmation of this as well :)